# How to pass value on UIButton click to delegate inside collectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning iOS programming for last few days, so I am new to this tech. I am building simple app where I'm using collection view which has EventCell inside it. Each EventCell has one UIButton and EventCell has uniq value(ID coming from JOSN API response). I need to pass that value to delegate which call new ViewController. I have setup the delegate method which is working correctly, just finding the solution for how to pass value on button click

PS: I am not using storyboard

```
**EventCell.swift**

lazy var leaderboardButton: UIButton = {
    let leaderboardBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
    leaderboardBtn.setTitle("LeaderBoard", for: .normal)
    leaderboardBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLeaderBoardClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    leaderboardBtn.tintColor = .white
    return leaderboardBtn
}()

weak var delegate: HomeControllerDelegate?
func handleLeaderBoardClick() {
    // need to get uniq value and pass here....
    delegate?.clickOnLeaderBoard()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass that ID value to delegate object which is in your case is your `ViewController` - then you need to modify `clickOnLeaderboard` function from the `HomeControllerDelegate` protocol.

Modify it and pass your EventCell's ID as an additional argument to it.

`delegate?.clickOnLeaderBoard(cellID)`

Also, don't forget to update function signature in view controller class.

Answer (score 0):

In `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` overload

add this:

```
cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row 
cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

you should have `buttonClicked(sender:)` in your UIViewController.

```
buttonClicked(sender:){
 tag = sender.tag
 // you can use this tag to change your view controller

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your function to include a parameter:

```
func handleLeaderBoardClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // need to get uniq value and pass here....
    delegate?.clickOnLeaderBoard()
}
```

Update the selector:

```
leaderboardBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLeaderBoardClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Now you can perform a comparison between `sender` and `leaderboardButton` to see if they're the same.

Comment: I get your point but how to get that uniq ID? in that function?

Comment: You can get the ID from the cell, right? Check the button's superview, which should be your cell.